# Grails - Use logical OR in CreateCriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many, createcriteria

Starting with the following Domains:

```
class Person {
    String login
    String name 
}

class MyDomain {
    Person creator
    static hasMany =  [userlist:Person]
}
```

I wrote a critera to retreive all MyDomainIntances where I'm as creator OR where I'm in the userlist:

```
def login = "myself"

def result =  MyDomain.createCriteria().list () {
    projections { distinct ( "id" )
        property("name")
        property("id")
    }
    or {             
       userlist{eq("login", login)}
       creator {eq("login",login)}
    }

    order("name","desc")
}
```

The problem is with this code I get only instances where I'm in the userlist.

Though `creator {eq("login",login)}` works well: if I use it itself only, I get a list where I'm as creator

---

**generated query:**

```
Hibernate:
select distinct this_.id as y0_,this_.name as y1_,this_.id as y2_
from mydomain this_ inner join person creator_al2_ on this_.creator_id=creator_al2_.id
                    inner join mydomain_person userlist5_ on this_.id=userlist5_.mydomain_userlist_id
                    inner join person userlist1_ on userlist5_.person_id=userlist1_.id
where ((userlist1_.login=?) or (creator_al2_.login=?))
order by this_.name desc
```

Comment: try `eq 'creator.login', login`

Comment: the query on the creator works well itself. I seems to be a condiational issue

Comment: no, conditional work well. I'd say you have a problem in the `projections`

Comment: I tested `eq 'creator.login', login` I had an exception. 
What I have to modify in the projections?

Comment: try to comment the projections out and see what you will get

Comment: I still not get the expected result

Comment: Enabled showSql = true and paste the generated query

Comment: I updated my question to display generated query

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the OR, as you state that you only get results where 'myself' is in the user list.  [This blog](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/grails-criteria-query-createalias-made-it-easy/) may help, which also cites [this helpful article](http://adhockery.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html) on createAlias.

```
def result =  MyDomain.createCriteria().list () {
    createAlias('creator', 'c')

    projections { distinct ( "id" )
        property("name")
        property("id")
    }

    or {             
       userlist{
           eq("login", login)
       }
       eq("c.login", login)
    }

    order("name","desc")
}
```

Comment: I tested your solution by using an alias, but I still have the same issue